# MPMusicPlayerController.shuffleMode cannot be set

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mpmusicplayercontroller

Hello I have a question about the `MPMusicPlayerController` in Swift. I am currently working on a Music App were I want to shuffle music by songs. So when the App Starts it basically sets the Playback Queue and then the Shuffle Mode. I can successfully set the queue (and play the songs) but I get an error when I set the Shuffle Mode:

```
musicPlayer.musicPlayer.shuffleMode = .songs
```

ERROR:

```
2018-07-03 15:01:36.450977+0200 Hitbeat[29053:8378883] [SDKPlayback] -[MPMusicPlayerController setShuffleMode:2] completed error: Error Domain=MPCPlayerRequestErrorDomain Code=1 "No commands provided." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No commands provided.}
```

What does that mean?
I have the idea that it may be because the queue is not set completely when setting the shuffleMode but I am not sure and it would not make any sense that one would have to set a song queue first in order to set the mode in which order songs to play. Maybe something else is the problem?

Also everything takes place on the Main Thread. (MPMusicPlayerController always has to be called in the Main Thread)

Thanks a lot I hope you guys can help me.

here are some code snippets:

MusicPlayerManager.swift

```
import os.log
import MediaPlayer
import NotificationCenter

class MusicPlayerManager {

    let musicPlayer: MPMusicPlayerController
    lazy var musicPickerAndAdder = MusicPickerAndAdder()

    init() {
        // Instantiate a new music player
        musicPlayer = MPMusicPlayerApplicationController.applicationQueuePlayer

        // Add a playback queue containing all songs on the device

        switch MPMediaLibrary.authorizationStatus() {
        case .authorized:
            let catalogSongStoreID: String = ""
            let catalogQueueDescriptor = MPMusicPlayerStoreQueueDescriptor(storeIDs: [catalogSongStoreID])
            musicPlayer.setQueue(with: catalogQueueDescriptor)

        default:
            break
        }

        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 15, repeats: false) {_ in
            print("shuffle mode setter")
            self.musicPlayer.shuffleMode = MPMusicShuffleMode.songs
        }
    }

    func updateOnlineMusicQueue() {
        var musicPickerIds = [String]()
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).sync {
            musicPickerIds = musicPickerAndAdder.ids
        }
        if !musicPickerIds.isEmpty{
        musicPlayer.setQueue(with: musicPickerIds)
        }else {
            updateOfflineMusicQueue()
        }
        musicPlayer.pause()
    }

    func play() {

        if musicPlayer.playbackState == .playing {
            musicPlayer.pause()
            musicPlayer.skipToBeginning()
        }

        if !musicPlayer.isPreparedToPlay {
            musicPlayer.prepareToPlay { (error) in
                if error == nil {
                    self.musicPlayer.play()
                    self.startSongMasterTimer()
                }
            }
        }else {
            musicPlayer.play()
            startSongMasterTimer()
        }

    }

    func pauseAndSkip() {
//        if self.musicPlayer.shuffleMode.rawValue != 2 { // does not work here would work on pause and skip
//            self.musicPlayer.shuffleMode = MPMusicShuffleMode.songs
//        }
        //print("shuffler \(self.musicPlayer.shuffleMode.rawValue)")

        //print("At \(musicPlayer.currentPlaybackTime) of \((musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem?.playbackDuration!)")
        musicPlayer.pause()
        //if musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem != nil {
        musicPlayer.skipToNextItem()
        //}
        musicPlayer.prepareToPlay { (error) in
            if error == nil {
                self.musicPlayer.pause()
            }
        }
    }

    func currentSongInfo() -> SongInfo {

        let songTitle = musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem?.title?.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: " ") ?? "" // To guarantee there is only one - between Song and Artist
        let artistName = musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem?.artist?.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: " ") ?? ""

        let songInfo = SongInfo(title: songTitle, artist: artistName)

        return songInfo
    }

    func addSongToLibrary() {
        //print("Id of Item to Add: \(musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem?.playbackStoreID)")
        if musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem != nil {
            musicPickerAndAdder.addResourceToUserMusicLibrary(resourceId: (musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem?.playbackStoreID)!)
        }

        //ToDo add to myHitbeat Playlist
    }

}

class SongInfo {
    let title: String
    let artist: String

    init(title:String,artist:String) {
        self.title = title
        self.artist = artist
    }
}
```

MusicPickerAndAdder.swift

```
import Foundation

class MusicPickerAndAdder {

    lazy var authorizationManager: AuthorizationManager = {
        return AuthorizationManager(appleMusicManager: self.appleMusicManager)
    }()

    var appleMusicManager = AppleMusicManager()

    private var idsArraySize = 100

    static var idCategoriesStakes = ["Chart_Ids" : 0.10,
                                     "Recently_Played_Ids" : 0.10,
                                     "Experiment_Ids" : 0.30,
                                     "Recommendations_Ids" : 0.50,] // Addition of all Values must be 1 (100%)


    private var chartIds: [String] {

        var chartsIds = [String]()
        let chartsIdsGroup = DispatchGroup()
        chartsIdsGroup.enter()

        let limit = Int(Double(idsArraySize) * MusicPickerAndAdder.idCategoriesStakes["Recently_Played_Ids"]!)
       appleMusicManager.performAppleMusicGetChartSongs(regionCode: Locale.current.regionCode?.lowercased() ?? "us", limit: limit) { (storeIds, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print("There was an Error getting Charts")
            chartsIdsGroup.leave()
            return
        }
        chartsIds = storeIds
        chartsIdsGroup.leave()
       }

        chartsIdsGroup.wait()
        print("Charts sucessfully fetched")
        return chartsIds
    }
    private var recentlyPlayedIds: [String] {

        var recentIds = [String]()
        let recentIdsGroup = DispatchGroup()
        recentIdsGroup.enter()

        let limit = Int(Double(idsArraySize) * MusicPickerAndAdder.idCategoriesStakes["Recently_Played_Ids"]!)
        appleMusicManager.performAppleMusicGetRecentlyPlayed(userToken: authorizationManager.userToken, limit: limit) {
            (storeIds, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("There was an Error getting Recently Played")
                recentIdsGroup.leave()
                return
            }

            recentIds = storeIds
            recentIdsGroup.leave()
            }

        recentIdsGroup.wait()
        print("Recently Played sucessfully fetched: \(recentIds)")
        return recentIds
    }
    private var experimentIds: [String] {
        return ["pl.u-XkD04oZIY0Kxrl"]
    }
    private var recommendationsIds: [String] {
        return [String]()
    }

    // Never request Ids  in Main (UI) Thread
    var ids: [String] {

            var ids = [String]()

            ids += recentlyPlayedIds
            ids += chartIds
            ids += experimentIds
            ids += recommendationsIds

            print("Store Ids for Songs \(ids)")
            return ids.shuffled() // shuffles list of items
    }

    init() {
        requestAppleMusicAuthorization()
    }
    //MARK: Private Methods
    private func requestAppleMusicAuthorization() {
        UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: ["tutorial": true])
        if !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "tutorial") {
            authorizationManager.requestCloudServiceAuthorization()
            authorizationManager.requestMediaLibraryAuthorization()
        }
    }

}

extension MusicPickerAndAdder { // to Add Songs
    func addResourceToUserMusicLibrary(resourceId: String) {
        appleMusicManager.performAddResourceToLibrary(resourceId: resourceId, userToken: authorizationManager.userToken)
    }
}

extension MutableCollection {
    /// Shuffles the contents of this collection.
    mutating func shuffle() {
        let c = count
        guard c > 1 else { return }

        for (firstUnshuffled, unshuffledCount) in zip(indices, stride(from: c, to: 1, by: -1)) {
            // Change `Int` in the next line to `IndexDistance` in < Swift 4.1
            let d: Int = numericCast(arc4random_uniform(numericCast(unshuffledCount)))
            let i = index(firstUnshuffled, offsetBy: d)
            swapAt(firstUnshuffled, i)
        }
    }
}

extension Sequence {
    /// Returns an array with the contents of this sequence, shuffled.
    func shuffled() -> [Element] {
        var result = Array(self)
        result.shuffle()
        return result
    }
}
```

PS: MusicPickerAndAdder may look a little messy though I don't think the problem lies there! What it basically does is fetching some data from the Apple Music API which works fine, and adding Songs to the User Library which works too.

Comment: nobody knowing the answer to this?

Comment: It would help a lot if you would show a significant stretch of actual code. We need to see what music player you are using, how you have prepared things, etc. The music player controller is very touchy if you don't get things exactly right.

Comment: alright thanks for taking time, I added some code hope it helps, because I am really not sure where the problem lies it got a little long, hope thats not a problem! Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks. Which line exactly fails? Is it the one in the Timer?

Comment: yes, I used to call it in init but then I figured out that when calling it a little after initialisation it would work better. Even tough now it does not happen all the time it happens in about 50% of the cases.

Comment: I find that things work better if (1) you pause first, and (2) you then introduce a very brief delay. So I would say: pause; then set the shuffle mode; then delay; then play. — Note that I have no difficulty at all setting the shuffle mode right after setting the queue.

Comment: Thanks I have the feeling this helps a little bit though it still happens a lot that the App freezes during setting it. Why does this even help do you have an explanation for that? (just curious) You think there is any way to avoid this freeze completely somehow?

Comment: Actually I lied (sorry). It looks like I am more successful if I go stop, set shuffle mode, set queue. I am not having much luck when I set the queue and then set shuffle mode (only works sometimes, as you said). So maybe it just doesn't like having the shuffle mode set when we already have a queue...?

Comment: hey I now figured out that my userToken was too old so I added a piece checking it and requesting a new one if needed. Now it seems to work. But can that really be? I set my code back to the one above and now I haven't experienced the freezing of the App yet. I set the music player queue with store Ids but can the user token really affect the setting of the shuffle mode?

Comment: I don't know what "freezing of the app" means. If the interface freezes, you need to be operating in a background thread.

Comment: yes the interface freezes. But wouldn't operating it on a background thread make things worse since Apple states in the Documentation under MPMusicPlayerController inside a "yellow important box": "You must use a music player only on your app’s main thread." https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmusicplayercontroller    or do I misunderstand something about that?

Comment: Very good point! Well, if the only thing causing the freeze is the command to the music player, I don't know what you can do. You should file a bug with Apple if they require use of the music player on the main thread but doing so freezes the interface.

Comment: I will definitely do that, yeah thats really weird you are right! I am using Xcode version 9.4.1 and Swift 4.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177505/discussion-between-matt-and-sirjoe).

Comment: I am occasionally get similar errors on different commands, not only shuffle mode setting. Opening Apple Music app, playing something there and coming back to my app helps me, which is quite shitty.

Comment: I'm having similar issues.  I'm constantly wondering if I should ditch this framework and go lower level to AVFoundation.  This framework does NOT work as advertised.  I've had to spend so much time trying to get my head around it, then to discover it also doesn't "just work".  Thanks for this comment thread!

Answer (score 2):

Okay after trying everything out possible I came up with two solutions that work for me. Weirdly I found out that a freeze of the interface only occurs when no song has played so far. If a song is currently playing or even if a song has played and was paused afterwards there is no ui freeze. So I came up with this function:

```
private func setShuffleMode() { // does work though startup and restarting takes longer

    musicPlayer.play()
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.5, repeats: false) {_ in
        print("shuffle mode setter")
        self.musicPlayer.pause()
        //self.musicPlayer.pause()// may stop interface freezing if occuring
        self.musicPlayer.shuffleMode = MPMusicShuffleMode.songs // freeze of ui only occurs when no song played before
    }
}
```

I tried out several time intervals it still failed sometimes if it was a second it never failed on 1.5 seconds so I left it there

The problem though was that starting the App as well as restarting it was taking a little bit longer. So I came up with a second solution

```
private func setShuffleMode2 () { // still in test if shuffle mode gets set fast or even ever set
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5, repeats: true) {timer in
        if self.musicPlayer.playbackState == .playing && self.musicPlayer.currentPlaybackTime > 3{
            self.musicPlayer.shuffleMode = .songs
            print("shuffle mode setter")
            timer.invalidate()
        }
    }
}
```

Here I have a repeating timer which is always checking if an item is playing and if it is playing for a certain time already, if it is it sets the shuffle mode and stops repeating. I have tested the second function and it worked great though there is the trade of that there is always the possibility that it is not getting called for some time. How long that will be depends on the time interval and currentPlaybackTime > someTime value.